# How to "intercept" site images from Magento static cms blocks

Tags: magento

I have an extension that overrides getSkinUrl() and intercepts images coming through it, makes changes, then continues.  This works for any images referenced in PHTML files.

However, This isn't catching images in CMS blocks.  In the CMS blocks, I'm using

```
{{skin url="images/your_amazing_image.gif"}}
```

Comment: What model instance is the `getSkinUrl()` method you are overriding a part of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento's template variables are defined in the following file.

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Email/Template/Filter.php`

For the `{{skin}}` variable, the following code is used around `line 264 in filter.php`

```
public function skinDirective($construction)
{
    $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
    $params['_absolute'] = $this->_useAbsoluteLinks;

    $url = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($params['url'], $params);

    return $url;
}
```

I'm not sure how you are overriding `getSkinUrl`, but make sure that the `getSkinUrl` method is the same method you are overriding.

Comment: Those `xyzDirective()` functions are invoked further up the chain, which may be a point to inject code; should suffice to do a standard rewrite of the calling class which I believe is actually `Mage_Cms_Model_Template_Filter`